# check if value exists in in database and if does redirect to a page using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

```
<?php 
    require_once("!cache.php");
    $connection = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'twa137', 'twa137hu',     'westernhotel137');

    if(!$connection) {
        die("connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $username="";
    $password="";
    $usmg="";
    $pasmg="";
    $logincorrect = "";

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        // Here we only validate that username and password are not empty. 

        $username = $_POST["username"];
        if (empty($username)) $usmg = '<span class="error"> This field is mandatory. Please enter staff ID.</span>';

        $password = $_POST["password"];
        if (empty($password)) $pasmg = '<span class="error"> This field is mandatory. Please enter password.</span>';

        if (strlen($usmg)==0 && strlen($pasmg)==0) {
            // sanitize them before passing to database
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $password);
            $sql = "select username, password from customers where username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
            $rs = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)
               or die("Error when looking up username and password" . mysqli_error($connection));

            if (mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0 ) {
                // username and password correct
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["who1"] = $username;

                $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
                mysqli_close($connection);
                $logincorrect = true;

                header("location: browse.php");
            }

            mysqli_close($connection);
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            input[type="text"] {
                border: 2px solid black;
            }
            .error {
                color:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Login page </h2>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
            <p>
            Admin name: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($username) ?>" />
            <?php echo $usmg; ?>
            </p>
            <p>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($password) ?>" />
            <?php echo $pasmg; ?>
            </p>
            <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
            </p>
            <p>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset"/>
            </p>
        </form>

        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !$logincorrect) {
                echo "<p> <span class='error'>Login details incorrect. Please try again!</span></p>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I need to check if the value exists and if it does it'll redirect to another page, but when i try to test my input it always shows login details incorrect, even if the value exists in the database

Comment: why 'enter code here' line is there for so many times....plz edit question

Comment: is your database password hashed or in any words, encrypted?

Comment: Sorry i am new here @DrManishJoshi

Comment: its in words @keziah

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
?><html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 input{
 border:1px solid olive;
 border-radius:5px;
 }
 h1{
  color:darkgreen;
  font-size:22px;
  text-align:center;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login<h1>
<form action='' method='post'>
<table cellspacing='5' align='center'>
<tr><td>User name:</td><td><input type='text' name='username'/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='password'/></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/></td></tr>
</table>

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','twa137','twa137hu','westernhotel137');

 $username=$_POST['username'];
 $password=$_POST['password'];
 if($username!=''&&$password!='')
 {
   $query=mysqli_query($connection,"select * from login where username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'");
   $res=mysqli_num_rows($query);
   if($res>0)
   {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
    header('location:browse.php');
   }
   else
   {
    echo'You entered username or password is incorrect';
   }
 }
 else
 {
  echo'Enter both username and password';
 }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its showing an error "Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in I:\twa\twa137\assignment1\adminlogin.php on line 37 You entered username or password is incorrect "  

also where should i start the session ?

Comment: i modified the code for session. check database connection,table and field names are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Before saving username and password into database you can do this. This is for secured form submission:

```
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$username = stripslashes($username);// This prevents accidental sql injection
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);
$password = md5($password); //Optional but secured as you are hashing the password
//here add your SQL query to save into database
```

This same method you can use for login and register of username and password. In the form you can remove the value as you will be entering the values. I also suggest you to start using PDO as that is more secured.